# Error using WebDriverManager.Net NuGet package on hosted agents

Tags: selenium, selenium-chromedriver, webdriver-manager, azure-devops-hosted-agent

I was wondering if someone could help with this issue we are facing running Selenium tests on an Microsoft Hosted Agent in Azure DevOps. We've recently attempted to implement WebDriverManager.Net to handle the fact that our local versions of Chrome do not match the versions on the Azure Hosted Agent. It also helps when the hosted agents have their version of Chrome updated. Whilst this works fine locally, we get the following issue in our pipeline run. We're simply calling this code to create an instance of the chromedriver:

```
new DriverManager().SetUpDriver(new ChromeConfig());
var webDriver = new ChromeDriver();
```

And this is the error we are facing:

```
System.Exception : Error writing D:\a\r1\a\Chrome\94.0.4606.61\X64
----> System.IO.IOException : **Source and destination path must have identical roots. Move will not work across volumes.**
TearDown : System.Exception : Error writing D:\a\r1\a\Chrome\94.0.4606.61\X64
----> System.IO.IOException : Source and destination path must have identical roots. Move will not work across volumes.
```

Any ideas on how to resolve this?

Comment: Update drivermanager... there's a note on the latest gitHub: "
Fix for error "Source and destination path must have identical roots...": https://github.com/rosolko/WebDriverManager.Net/tree/master/WebDriverManager

Comment: Thank you! Looks like the fix was posted an hour before I created this topic. It does however look like a new version of the NuGet package hasn't been published yet, so I will revert back to version 2.11.3 until a new one is pushed.